# Did Pirates have any unique Mythos or Races we don't really know of?

Tags: mythology

I am writing many short stories to understand the world I'm building before diving into the main thing.

All races and species take ideas from real-world cultures, mythology and religions with some homebrew mixed in to tie it together, atm I'm working on a pirate republic-type thing and I'm fine-tuning the details of their whole thing.

So as the title says, did they have any unique stuff like Davy Jones that we don't really know about, for instance, the Kraken originates from Scandinavia, Calypso from Rome and so on.

Also races like mermaids, did they believe in other races that dwelled in the ocean below them that I could use as a conflict or integrate them into the pirate society, I found a thing called a Sea Bishop which is definitely making it in, but any others that google doesn't mistake for Pirates of the Caribbean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Minus one for spreading the fake news that Calypso originates from Rome. She does not. (As a clue, if a word contains the letter **y** or one of the digraphs **th** or **ph**, it is not a native Latin word. **Ch** also, except in a few words such as *pulcher*.)

Comment: Calypso is the nymph who Odysseus lives with in the Odyssey. At least as old as the Greeks. Older than the Romans.

Comment: @Daron: And she has a pure Greek name = The Concealeress, from [*kalýptō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/καλύπτω#Ancient_Greek) "I hide (something)"...

Comment: Hi SassySkrub. Know that looking for historical references is not what worldbuilding stack-exchange is best at (it is aimed at solving specific problems than ideas gathering), nor is it what it is for : without the "building" part directly tied to the question it is more pure history on myths and beliefs. A better fit question would be trying to incorporate a myth you want to add into your world, for instance an hell of fire into an ocean, or mixing sirens and medusas together :).

Answer (score 1):

Pirates are not a culture. They aren't even a subculture, they are pirates.

This is kinda like asking if terrorists have their own religion that only they follow, or if theives have superstitions only they believe in. Pirates are criminal groups of the culture they were a part of before they became pirates. So they believed in the same things,more or less, as they did when they weren't pirates.

Now, this does not need to be true in your world. You can make pirates a completely different culture from other sailors. This may have unfortunately implications, because it's kinda like say the bandits are all one culture which is different from the other people, but it's certainly something you can do. It wouldn't have much basis in reality though.

Answer (score 0):

## Maritime Superstitions

[image]

Sailors are a superstitious lot. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailors%27_superstitions) or [here](https://piratesforums.co/threads/pirate-superstitions.2750/).

I suggest you take real or imagined sailor superstitions and make them a bit more piratey.